# mimekit IMAP - Proxy C#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток, я использую библиотеку mimekit, для работы с IMAP.
Но переискав весь интернет, я ничего толком и не нашел.
Перелопатил кучу других IMAP библиотек, то поиск писем работает через заднее место, то нету документации как использовать прокси, и вообще можно ли у них использовать прокси. Такой вопрос, может кто знает, какую то библиотеку, или как можно использовать прокси в данной библиотеке, либо же в ImapX - Там такая же проблема с прокси.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека mimekit является всего лишь парсером. Вы должны предварительно подготовить(создать,скачать)MIME-контент на который и натравите библиотеку.

Предположительно у Вас связка MailKit + Mimekit.
Одним из параметров метода connect(), библиотеки MailKit, является socket.
Соответственно Вам необходимо самостоятельно реализовать функционал прокси и передать свой socket в метод connent.
Чтобы не листать спецификацию предложу воспользоваться готовым решением [ProxySocket](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=9).

```
string server = "imap.yandex.ru";
int port = 993;
string proxyIP = "0.0.0.0";
int proxyPort = 1080;


client = new ImapClient() // imap клиент

...    
ProxySocket socket = new ProxySocket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.ProxyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(proxyIP ), proxyPort);
socket.ProxyType = ProxyTypes.Socks4;
socket.Connect(server, port);
if (socket.Connected)
{
      client.Connect(socket, server, port);
}
...
```